# MongoDB Linq date difference in WHERE statement

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, datetime

I have a class, that contains two DateTime variables, "From" and "To":

```
public class A
{
    public DateTime From;
    public DateTime To;
}
```

If I'd want to get all objects, where From and Two are only 2 hours apart, I'd write something like this:

```
_db.GetCollection<A>("A").Find( (x.To-x.From).TotalMinutes <= 120).ToList();
```

or

```
var Minutes120 = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
_db.GetCollection<A>("A").Find( (x.To-x.From) <= Minutes120).ToList();
```

or even

```
var Minutes120 = new TimeSpan(0, 120, 0).Ticks;
_db.GetCollection<A>("A").Find( (x.To.Ticks-x.From.Ticks) <= Minutes120).ToList();
```

However, none of the above work. I always get **"...is not supported."** error.

Is there any way of doing a search like above without having to save the time difference together with the dates in a separate property? It seems a little overkill to save the time difference although I need it only in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [query reference of mongo db](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) there are no arithmetic operators. This means that your query, using such operators, cannot be translated into a MongoDB query.

Alternatives to adding the member are thus,

1) expand the query and put your expression in a Where clause after the ToList() (in-memory .NET calculation comparison of all differences)

2) use the [aggregation methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) of the MongoDB engine which is a possible way to do queries: Aggregate on your From and To fields, perhaps with `$sum` or something and end with `$match` on your results with your 120 minute requirement. Remember that the output of an aggregation is [not really a class of yours anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072152/mongodb-result-set-for-aggregate) (as you have introduced a new member).  [Here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c) is a great article on searching and calculating with the aggregation functions.